# Will this ODroid-C1 3,2" touch screen work with Raspberry 2?

Tags: display, touchscreen

I bought a 3,2" touch screen which was [advertised](http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/OTk1OTgxOTk-/Bausaetze_Module/Entwicklerboards/Odroid/ODROID_C1_8_13_cm_3_2_TFT_Display_mit_Touchscreen.html) (German website) for Raspbery and ODroid-C1:

> Wird einfach auf den ODROID-C1 oder Raspberry Pi Einplatinencomputer aufgesteckt!

Translated:

> Is simply plugged onto your ODROID-C1 or Raspberry Pi single board computer.

After it was shipped, the manual says

> Dieses TFT-Display darf nur in Verbindung mit dem ODROID-C1 verwendet werden.

Translated:

> This TFT display must only be used with the ODROID-C1.

So now I wonder whether it's safe to connect it to the Raspberry Pi 2, since I don't own a ODROID-C1.

Link to [hardkernel](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G142060963922), which seems to be the original producer. Depending on the pin numbering system, I can only figure out that the 3.3V and 5.0V power supply could match.

Comment: YOLO. But on a more serious note: you probably got a different product since the one on the site *specifically states* that it's for *ODROID or RasPi* but then you got a screen *that's for ODROID only*.

Comment: I quickly checked and the SPI interface seems to be pin compatible between the two which is a prerequisite. But even if you still need to have an appropriate driver on the RaspberryPi. To safe yourself some trouble I would recommend buying a display which is supported by notro: https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried: Yes, it's safe to connect the 3,2" touch screen.

While it didn't display anything (completely white display), I could still attach an HDMI monitor and operate with it. It sometimes displayed the "battery warning" icon in the top right corner, but never failed on a 2A power supply.

To get something displayed, I mainly followed [the instructions of the Raspberry Forum](http://www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-odroid-c1-touchscreen-waveshare-3-2-b-unter-raspbian-jessi-raspi-1-2). Here's the sequence that made it work for me:

1. `wget http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/9/9d/LCD-show-151020.tar.gz`
2. `tar xvf LCD-show-151020.tar.gz`
3. `cd LCD-show/`
4. `sudo ./LCD32-show` (which will reboot)
5. `cd LCD-show/`
6. `sudo dpkg -i xinput-calibrator_0.7.5-1_armhf.deb`
7. `sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=waveshare32b rotate=270 gpios=dc:22,reset:27`

At this time, I saw the output on the ODroid 3,2" display. After an additional `startx` I also saw the Raspbian desktop.

Unfortunately I was not able to calibrate the touchscreen and I was not able to apply the changes permanently. After a reboot, the display was white again.