# Making the admatec C-Berry 3.2" display the primary screen

Tags: display

After I had a few [issues with the ODroid C1 3.2" display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45911/will-this-odroid-c1-3-2-touch-screen-work-with-raspberry-2) I now bought an admatec C-Berry 3.2" display for the same purpose. Unlike the nice 7" display I have and that is auto-detected, this 3.2" display remained black after attaching it electronically.

So I built the BCM2835 library:

```
wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.48.tar.gz
tar zxvf bcm2835-1.48.tar.gz
cd bcm2835-1.48
./configure
make
sudo make check
sudo make install
cd ..
```

And built the C-Berry:

```
wget http://admatec.de/sites/default/files/downloads/C-Berry.tar.gz
tar xzf C-Berry.tar.gz
cd C-Berry/SW/fb2cberry
make -C .
cd ../tft_test
make -C .
sudo ./tft_test
```

I can now `startx`, open a Terminal and run `sudo fb2cberry` to mirror the main HDMI display to the small screen, but

**How to I set up the 3,2" display as the main screen to run in native resolution?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are two ways to go about this. Method one is to somehow go into raspi-config and force DSI output (which I don't know how to do, but is probably easier). Method two is to implement the code you mentioned above into the Pi's boot code (which is done by writing it in some file, I forgot its name :/ ), which will mirror the main HDMI display automatically during bootup.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you could remember how to do at least one of the possible solutions.